# why does the if always print empty? attempting to test whether passed in variable is set?

Tags: csh

I'm trying to write a csh alias (and yes it has to be csh, god I wish it didn't). I'd like to pass in a variable name and depending on whether it is set or not operate on it. I've boiled the code down to the following. What puzzles me is the first echo prints 1 or 0 depending on if the value is set or not, but the echo in the if always prints empty.

```
alias trythis 'eval echo \$\?\!:1 ; eval if \$\?\!:1 then ; echo empty ; endif ; '
```

what's suppose to happen is if you pass in PATH it shouldn't print anything, but if you pass in PATHx it should print empty. (and yes, the if is probably backwards, but I ripped out the ! to make things even simpler)

so trythis PATH should print empty, and trythis PATHx should print nothing

Comment: tried this : alias trythis 'eval set xxx=\$\?\!:1 ; echo $xxx ; if ( $xxx ) then ; echo empty ; endif ; '   but now it's complaining about the if when the $xxx is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misleading part about your original code is that you didn't properly have the semi-colons escaped for your second eval statement, e.g. the following part:

`eval if \$\?\!:1 then ; echo empty ; endif ;`

Here you have three statements to be executed by the shell:

- `eval if \$\?\!:1 then` - this will silently fail / do-nothing
- `echo empty` - this will always print *empty*
- `endif` - this will do nothing (not sure why csh doesn't complain here)

Here's an updated version with escape semi-colons so that you execute the previous three statements as a single statement:

`alias trythis 'eval echo \$\?\!:1 ; eval if \$\?\!:1 then \; echo empty \; endif ;'`

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want to put multiple commands in the if. Are you looking for a way to test the results of multiple commands in one single if statement or something else? Perhaps this is a new stack overflow question.

Comment: something else. I want to do 'if ($x) then ; cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; endif

Comment: and the semicolon's need to be escaped to preserve them through the eval? didn't think about that. thanks.

Comment: Ah. What you just typed will work in that comment will do what you want because you have a properly formatted if/endif block. In your original code you did not because you had a malformed eval statement.

Comment: For further clarification, you don't need to escape the semi-colons in the example of `if($x) ; then cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; endif.` 

However, you do when you  pipe everything through an eval statement because you need to pass the whole thing as a string to eval. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just found this works:

```
 alias trythis 'eval set xxx=\$\?\!:1 ; echo $xxx ; if ( $xxx == 0 ) echo empty ; '
```

I guess there's a form of the if that doesn't take a then. glad I'm not trying to fit many commands in the if. csh really puzzles me with it's syntax.

if anybody can show how to put multiple commands with the if, that would be great